# fetch PDO::FETCH_ASSOC multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, html

usually i help people with whatever they need, this time i'm asking for your help.

i'm trying to get a specific row from my database after preforming multiple checkbox select  i spend 50 hours on that and i couldn't manage to do that.
each time i'm changing something in my code i get a different ERROR.
i was looking for an answer in every HTML page that exist on the INTERNET !

please show me the light..

here is a part of my form.... value means "size" of the toy

```
    <div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="toys[]" value="6X2" /><label></label></div>
    <div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="toys[]" value="4X3" /><label></label></div>
    <div class=""><input type="checkbox" name="toys[]" value="8X2.5" /><label></label></div></strike>
```

here is the PHP code...

```
  if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {

     foreach($_POST['toys'] as $each_check) {

      }
  }

  $query = $db->query = 'SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = '.$each_check;   


echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
            <th>ratio</th>
            <th>size</th>
            <th>built</th>
            <th>description</th>            
          </tr>";



while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ratio'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['built'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row['description'] .
            "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Are you by chance mixing `MySQLi` with PDO?

Comment: thank you for your fast comment.. but the answer is no.

Comment: I noticed your edit. This `value="8X2.5"` is invalid. You cannot have a dot and PHP is probably thinking that you're wanting to do a calculation. Use an underscore instead as in `value="8X2_5"`

Answer (score 2):

This is so very far from being valid:

```
if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {

    foreach($_POST['toys'] as $each_check) {

    }
}

$query = $db->query = 'SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = '.$each_check;
```

More like:

```
if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {
    foreach($_POST['toys'] as $each_check) {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = '".$each_check."'");
    }
}
```

But *should* be more like:

```
if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = ?';
    $sth = $db->prepare($query);
    foreach($_POST['toys'] as $each_check) {
        if( ! $sth->execute(array($each_check)) ) {
            die('MySQL Error: ' . var_export($sth->error_info(), TRUE);
        }
        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `('SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = '.$each_check)` be `("SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = '".$each_check."' ")` since the numbers need to be treated as a string? (from values)

Comment: Probably, but that's the *least* of OP's many, many errors. Changing in my code I guess...

Comment: For sure. One of the reasons I didn't bother putting in an answer without actually recreating everything and testing.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `$db->query` instead of using it as a function. Change your query line to this:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE SIZE = :size');
$query->bindValue(':size',$each_check);
$query->execute();
```

Also, you're going through $_POST['toys'], but not assigning it to any value. I'm guessing you want to add all of your query and table code within the foreach.

```
if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {
    foreach($_POST['toys'] as $each_check) {
        // put everything else here
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the error i get... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '6X2' in 'where clause'

Comment: Since the size is a string, it needs to be quoted. Prepared statements would be better to prevent injection and make sure everything is quoted correctly. I'll update with that.

Comment: you mean that i need to add "6X2" for each size in size column ?

Comment: Before, it was evaluating "SIZE = 6X2" and looking for 6X2 as a column name. When you're trying to find the value '6X2' within the column SIZE, you need to quote the string. "SIZE = '6X2'"

Comment: @aynber PHP/SQL might even be thinking/trying to do calculations as well if not properly quoted/escaped. `6X2=12` ;-)

Comment: i tried but i'ts not working , can you please give an example, i am willing to pay if you can solve this issue..

Comment: @hagay Did you not read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711710/fetch-pdofetch-assoc-multiple-checkboxes#comment29283456_19711710) ? Also check your column names/spelling etc. `SIZE` is not the same as `size` if that is the case. Also check to see what those columns are set as, `VARCHAR` or `INT` or other.

Comment: hello Fred, i did read your comment and i'm trying to do something with it, i'll double check what you offered and i can a sure you that if you solve this issue for me you will earn from that :) thank you !!!

Comment: OK, i don't get any errors but i don't get the row from the database. i assume that now i have a problem with that line ->->->   $query = 'SELECT * FROM `billbords` WHERE "size = 6X2"';

Comment: also size in my database is set as VARCHAR (15)

Comment: Have you tried that command within mysql cli/phpmyadmin to make sure it brings up results? The query should be "SELECT * FROM billbords WHERE size= '6X2'". Note that the whole where shouldn't be quoted, just the string you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest that you use MySQL's IN (...) clause in your WHERE condition to retrieve all the rows with matching 'size' in just 1 query:

```
SELECT * FROM toys WHERE size IN ( $chosenSizes )
```

To get the list of sizes, use PHP's implode function:

```
$chosenSizes = implode(', ', $_POST['toys']);
```

You can then use PDO's fetchAll to fetch all rows into a result array.

```
$resultRows = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Note: Only use this method when you are quite certain that the result arrays is not too big!

Comment: hello kDjarkman - thank you !!! , i did that now , here is my try , still no errors and no table row output.. ->->-> $chosenSizes = implode(', ', $_POST['toys']);

Comment: $query = 'SELECT * FROM `toys` WHERE size IN '.$chosenSizes;

Comment: till now no one could explain how to do it on html page or in YouTube... how can it be possible ? someone should give a full explanation on how to work with multiple CheckBoxes.. and query them into a table from a database (those that the user selected of course!)

Comment: To be certain, the IN clause of MySQL needs opening and closing parentheses to delimit the list.  Also I missed the fact that sizes are not integer but strings, so you have to quote each value.

Answer (score 0):

Hagay, the following should work for you:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'my_name', 'my_pass');

if (isset($_POST['toys'])) {
    $sizes = implode(', ', array_map(array($pdo, 'quote'), $_POST['toys']));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM toys WHERE size IN (" . $sizes . ")";

    echo '<table>', PHP_EOL;
    echo '<tr><th>ratio</th><th>size</th></tr>', PHP_EOL;

    foreach( $pdo->query($sql) as $row ) {
       echo '<tr><td>', $row['ratio'], '</td><td?', $row['size'],  '</td></tr>', PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
}
```